# I am not able to insert the content of table 1 into table 2 in sql using Php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


for($i=0;$i<=feof($getdata);$i++)
{
if (filter_var($data[$i][1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo $data[$i][1];
$email=$data[$i][1];

$name=$data[$i][0];
$sql ="INSERT INTO promo_user (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$sql .="INSERT INTO promo_type (uid) select uid from promo_user";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

this is my code here i am first inserting some content (name and email) into table  promo_user and then trying to insert the uid from promo_user to table promo_type but this is not working the content is going to table promo_user but not to promo_type 
please help

Comment: Is that `.=` there deliberate and if so, what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting get the insert id

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO promo_user (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$uid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
$sql ="INSERT INTO promo_type set uid =$uid";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thanks, But this code is show  some error..PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/qh/csv.php ..

Comment: try it now i forgot semicolon

Comment: if is helped you, you need to accep it as the correct answer